# setCallbackHandler function with multiple inputs

Tags: ajax, coldfusion

I am sure there is a simple answer to this one, I'm just too new to Ajax to see it.

I am using CF 9 and i am trying to setup the callbackfuntion to take multiple inputs, however, I don't know the default name of the results from the ajax call.

here is what works:

```
var mySSN = document.getElementById("SSN");
var cfc = new myajax();
cfc.setCallbackHandler(UpdateValidationNotes);
cfc.ValidateSSN(mySSN.value);
```

And here is what i am trying to do:

```
var mySSN = document.getElementById("SSN");
var cfc = new myajax();
cfc.setCallbackHandler(UpdateValidationNotes(MyField, AjaxResults);
cfc.ValidateSSN(mySSN.value);
```

However, i don't know how to reference the ajax results since the callback handler is doing it automagically.  Can anyone help out the lose newbie?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a try like this,

```
var mySSN = document.getElementById("SSN");
var cfc = new myajax();
cfc.setCallbackHandler(function(AjaxResults) {UpdateValidationNotes(MyField, AjaxResults);});
cfc.ValidateSSN(mySSN.value);
```

Comment: The other way worked, but this is sooo much better!  Thanks for the info!!

Answer (score 1):

The callback handler function can only take one argument, which will be passed to your handler function automagically. This will be the return value from the CFC that the proxy has deserialized from JSON to a JavaScript representation.([see CFAjaxProxy docmentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_a-b_3.html))

When you call `setCallbackHandler`, you just pass the function with no arguments.

It looks like you are trying to determine which field you just validated to possibly display a notice if it doesn't validate. In such cases, what I do is submit the field name to the server and have the server return it back in the response.

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to do. I didn't want to have to write a million mini functions that all did the same thing (update a div with a note).  Looks like my only option is as you stated, pass it to the server and pass it back.